# The name of control that can be switched from detail view to gridview, listview

Tags: wpf, list, grid, controls, detailview

I want to implement this control in my WPF project but i don't know what name of this control is?
[image]
Did anyone work on this before? Please give me info about this control.
Thanks

Comment: There's nothing like that in WPF (that I know of), though you can build it 100% custom in less than 1 hour.

Answer (score 0):

You mean the toolbar?
It doesn't exist, you've got to implement it yourself, create different datatemplates for each kind of view you want, then switching between them on click

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create these kind of views you can create custom views for listview [check out here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748859.aspx)

Although if you want ot know the name of the control. then use the [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to genrate the WPF visual tree for you and then you can see the names of the control is being rendered. on the controls.

Or the other way use the [VisualTreeHelper.GetChild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.getchild.aspx) methods

```
// Enumerate all the descendants of the visual object. 
static public void EnumVisual(Visual myVisual)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(myVisual); i++)
    {
        // Retrieve child visual at specified index value.
        Visual childVisual = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(myVisual, i);

        // Do processing of the child visual object. 

        // Enumerate children of the child visual object.
        EnumVisual(childVisual);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first level of enquiry would be to determine if the control is actually a WPF control.  To do that, you can use the WPF Snoop Utility.  If the utility detects WPF controls, it will produce a screen like this...

[image: Snoop display]

As shown in this image, you will be able to examine the visual tree and confirm that it is in fact a WPF control.  After that, it's down to locating the Xaml the author used and redeploying it in your app.  If you cannot get the Xaml, you will have to use Snoop (or another similar utility) to "reverse engineer" the control.

Snoop is here... https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/

If you cannot get the Xaml, or it is not a WPF control, then you have "reverse engineer" from scratch.  HighCore has indicated that it's a trivial task and I agree with him.

If you can actually obtain an instance of the control, you can use this method to get the template...

```
    public void DefaultControlTemplateLoaded(TreeView sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        XmlWriterSettings xmlSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        xmlSettings.Indent = true;
        using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringBuilder, xmlSettings))
        {
            XamlWriter.Save(sender.ItemsPanel, xmlWriter);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(stringBuilder.ToString());
    }
```

To do that you would have to load the assembly and poke around until you found the declaration and use the Activator to create an instance.

Be sure the product has a license that permits 'reverse engineering'!